# IntelliJ - java compilier error for generated JPA metamodel

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I am generating metamodel classes for my entities using gradle.

```
plugins {
    id "at.comm_unity.gradle.plugins.jpamodelgen" version "1.1.4"
}

jpaModelgen {
    library = "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.3.3.Final"
    jpaModelgenSourcesDir = "src/jpaModelgen/java"
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDir file("src/jpaModelgen/java")
```

From `gradle build` it works fine and compiling, but under IntelliJ when I try to build the project it gives me several errors for generated classes. While building all metamodel classes have problems with:
`error: package javax.persistence.metamodel does not exist` or `error: cannot find symbol class XXXX`.

The strange thing about this is even if compiler marks errors after I open this class there are no problems with imports nor packages. What can I do to make build valid?

Comment: and where is the javax.persistence api jar in the classpath? you know, the one with that package in it, that it says doesn't exist

Comment: it is under dependencies in gradle `compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed build.gradle to:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-jpamodelgen', version: '5.3.3.Final'
}

idea {
   module {
       sourceDirs += file("build/generated/src/main/java")
   }
}
```

And it work now properly.